# Remapping of esc to tab key in vim?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscodevim

How to remap or configure ESC key to TAB key in visual studio code for vim?
Operating system : Windows 11
Extension in visual studio code : vscodevim

I have tried to remap but unable to find the correct file to paste the configurations.I am not able to find the correct settings.json file to configure esc to tab key. How to do it?